# iMacros select context menu element

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation, imacros, browser-automation

**First, what do I want to do?**

I want to automate a process on Facebook (no black hat stuff). 
I want a program that adds people who shared a post to a Chrome addon.

I manually open the Facebook "Shared List"
Then I want to have a code that does the following:

1. Go to person number 1.
2. Right Click on name (context menu opens).
3. Go down to "Tool" on context menu.
4. Click on "Tool" (in order to add person to Chrome Addon)
5. Go to person number 2 and repeat the process.
6. Repeat process for all 400 people in the "Shared List"

Here is a screenshot of what I mean.

[My Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCAls.png)

**Second, this is what I did so far**

I could only right click on the first name in iMacros:

EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV" BUTTON=2

I don´t even think what I want to do is possible with iMacros. I figured out that iMacros is for HTML elements and the context menu is not a HTML element.
I researched all day long but I could (for the life of me) not figure out how to do it. I came across a few iMacro alternatives like Selenium (couldn´t even set that up), AutoHotKey, UiPathSutdio but I really could not figure out how to do it.

I am very new to programming and very lost. I´d appreciate help a lot.

Comment: First I used, iMacros Chrome addon.

Comment: Then I downloaded the enterprise version.

Comment: Yes you are right,as Right click options are not HTML elements you can try to use robot class for the same to click your option on pop-up.